# Grails Production mode - too many redirects

Tags: grails, deployment, web-deployment, tomcat8

I decided to rewrite this question, because the original description was wrong.

I am facing too many redirects in browser when running my app in production mode or trying to build war in production mode.

Everything works fine in development mode.

Here is the link to the demo.

http://ikariera.eu:8080/

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.8.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:6.0.1"
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC4'
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "ikariera3"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}
final SELENIUM_VERSION = "2.53.0"
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"

    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"

    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:5.0.0.RC2'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC6'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.9'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:cookie:2.0.5'

    compile 'org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2'

    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.0.6'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"

    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC4'
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'

    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$SELENIUM_VERSION"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$SELENIUM_VERSION"



}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'grails-app/migrations'
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my spring configuration:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/login/auth' // '/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/'


grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.filterProcessesUrl = '/logout/index'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.filterProcessesUrl = '/security/login_acccess_check'    //Login form post URL, intercepted by Spring Security filter.
grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.usernameParameter = 'security_username'  //    Login form username parameter.
grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.passwordParameter = 'security_password'  //    Login form password parameter.


grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true

grails.plugin.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.basic.realmName = "iKariera"


grails.plugin.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->

    cz.ikariera.security.User.withTransaction {
        def user = cz.ikariera.security.User.get(appCtx.springSecurityService.principal.id)
        user.lastLoginDate = new Date()
        user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
}

grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'cz.ikariera.security.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'cz.ikariera.security.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'cz.ikariera.security.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'cz.ikariera.security.Requestmap'


grails.plugin.springsecurity.dao.reflectionSaltSourceProperty = 'username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.adh.errorPage = null

grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/fonts/**',    access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/check',          access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**',             access: ["ROLE_ADMIN"]]
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/fonts/**',    filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS'],
]
```

The method implementation should be the default one for Spring Security.

---

There should not be an issue with my production specific configuration. I tried my production configuration in development mode and it works. I tried multiple hibernate4 versions aswell as hibernate5. I tried downgrading spring security and it did not help either.

Comment: You should provide more info. Without url-mapping, config and `http://ikariera.eu:8080/login/auth` logic it'll be hard to find out what's going on.

Comment: @Michal_Szulc see my edit.

Comment: Did you try to deploy it on localhost tomcat?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc Yes, but only used grails dev war, because there were some errors in production, which I did not want to bother back then. E.g. maxAge: 10 * 60000 has to be maxAge: 600000. I fixed them later. It seems that the problem is in the production mode itself and not in war generation.

Comment: are tomcat and java versions on localhost and on production the same?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc Yes, It is not the problem with production MIchal. It is a problem with production mode. It does the same thing when I run the app on localhost in production mode.